# Codeigniter 2.0.3 and Adodb Integration/Installation

Tags: codeigniter, adodb, codeigniter-2

How do you integrate Codeigniter 2.0.3 and Adodb?

Comment: whats your reasoning for using Adodb over the standard methods included in CI? Are you unable to do something that you can with Adodb?

Comment: The standard method would not show the data from the MS SQL

Comment: I'm making guesses here as your question is VERY limited in details, but that could be because your apache setup didn't have a mssql driver enabled?

Comment: I enable the mssql.dll from the PHP ext directory

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ADODB/

Comment: To ask again, why? That monolythic library is exactly why things like ActiveRecord exist. We have MSSQL drivers that work just fine. "Does not show data" is not a valid error report, try again.

Comment: You know Jakub, we decided to drop AdobeDb and use the CodeIgniter database settings. We needed to install SQL server drivers from Microsoft Web site.

Comment: Using CI_DB to retrieve bulk data (like 1000+ rows) is really slow vs ADODB. CI_DB takes 44.7054 on `->result()` while ADODB takes only 0.0102 on `foreach` of all results, tested on the same page over a (relatively) slow database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example (done with a MSSQL db, but adjust it to your db) :

1. download the ADOdb library from :
      http://www.ciforge.com/trac/adodb/ or 
      http://adodb.sourceforge.net/#download
2. Unzip the library to someplace on your server which can be called from your php pages
3. Connect using something like this:

   ```
   include('path/to/adodb/library/adodb/adodb.inc.php');      
   $db =& ADONewConnection('odbc_mssql');
   $dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=XXXX_dev;";

   $db->Connect($dsn,'username','password');
   $rs = $db->Execute('select * from table_name');

    while (!$rs->EOF) {           
        echo "loop: " . $rs->fields[5] . "<br>";
        $rs->MoveNext();       
    }

   $rs->Close();

   $rs->Close();
   ```

you may also take a look at [this solution](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/65672/)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. The explanation from the first link is very confusing and it doesn't work.

Comment: I checked out the 2nd link before I went to StackOverflow because the information on the 2nd link is outdated.

Comment: Hi Mona, I have a question regarding the step number 3. Where do you insert in the code? I tried to insert it in the database.php but it says that the code can't be processed as arrays.

Comment: in this example its just in the file that is gonna display the returned fields (it doesnt have to be in a config file ) , for more see this : http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm